# How to fix this terrain behavior?

Tags: unity, terrain, terrain-rendering, tessellation

EDIT: This is for In game Terraforming, kind of like in life is feudal. https://www.google.com/search?q=life+is+feudal+terraforming&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS792US792&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj73bS6lo7bAhUHzoMKHYlWBhoQ_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=949

Ediiting pixels vertically makes a line, but horizontally makes a peak the edited terrain pixels are adjacent. The height map resolution is 513.

[image]

When I turn on shaded wireframe in scene view, the issue becomes clearer.
[image]
When the terrain is tessellated, each vertex/terrain pixel is part of 6 edges. I suppose to fix this issue I would need to double the triangles, having each vertex be part of 8 edges.

What, if any, method could I use to achieve this and rid this behavior?

Comment: If you want sharp features like this, terrain might not be the right tool for the job. It's mainly aimed at gently sloping/organic/natural-looking landscapes. Can you tell us more about the application or feature you're using this for? We might be able to propose more suitable options.

Comment: In game Terraforming, kinda like in life is feudal.

Comment: Procedural mesh building might be the solution for you.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin can you elaborate?

Comment: @Astrydax Take a look: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html

Comment: Ah, so i'd need to do away with unity built in terrain system altogether?

Comment: I can't seem to get a reference to the terrain mesh. And building my on mesh from code wouldn't give me the terrain sculpting tools i would need

Comment: @Astrydax You need to code it on your own to replicate unity terrain. It is not very complex, just a bit tedious. I'm pretty sure I saw an asset doing this somewhere, but it was a long time ago and I can't remember it right now. You might find it on google with a smart search phrase.

Comment: You can't assume that everyone here has played *Life is Feudal*. So when you don't provide a description which can be understood by someone who isn't familiar with that game, then you exclude a lot of people who might be able to provide useful answers.

Comment: @philipp https://www.google.com/search?q=life+is+feudal+terraforming&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS792US792&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj73bS6lo7bAhUHzoMKHYlWBhoQ_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=949